# Disproving the statement "$x^2\ne x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$"

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I am learning discrete mathematics in school and one of the practice question says:

1. Find a counterexample for these quantifiers,  where the domain for
   all variables consists of all real numbers.

a) $ \forall x\ (x^2\neq x) $ for $ x\in \mathbb{R}$

Is this all I need to say?

if we let $ x= 1$ or $x= 0$ this statement is False.

Comment: Yes, more or less. Note that $-1$ is not right.  But one counterexample is enough.

Comment: you are absolutely right.. silly mistake.

Comment: Note that the universally quantified version is just plain false. The *reason* is that $0^2\ne 0$ is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given proposition means that the square of every real number is unequal to itself. The negation of this proposition is exactly: there is a real number whose square equals itself. But this is so, for $1^{2} = 1$. This disproves the original proposition.

Note that to disprove a universal proposition we only need to give exactly one counterexample.